# ARMv6 Assembly language

Tags: assembly, armv6

Does anyone know how to start a comment (e.g. '#',';', '/', '/*') in ARMv6 Assembly Language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be ";" as per some example code i found on the [wikipedia article:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)

```
    loop  CMP  Ri, Rj   ; set condition "NE" if (i != j),
                        ;               "GT" if (i > j),
                        ;            or "LT" if (i < j)
    SUBGT  Ri, Ri, Rj   ; if "GT" (greater than), i = i-j;
    SUBLT  Rj, Rj, Ri   ; if "LT" (less than), j = j-i;
    BNE  loop           ; if "NE" (not equal), then loop
```

Comment: Excellent - the one place I didn't think to look. This is the same as the 80x86 comment, and what I was thinking it was, but unsure. Thanks Alex!

Comment: And that's what's in use in most assemblers.

Comment: This is very much assembler-dependent.  The gnu assembler will accept '@' as a line comment marker.  Most preprocessing assemblers will accept C-style // and /* */ comments.  ARMCC uses ;.

Comment: I use ;@ so that it works on the warped gnu solution and the sane solution.